# How to get directory name and save to file, prefix IP adress

Tags: windows, batch-file

How could I get the directory names (c:\dirs) and save them to a file (C:\windows\system32\drive\etc\hosts).

Structure c:\dirs

```
c:\dirs\mypage1
c:\dirs\mypage2
c:\dirs\mypage3
```

Desired result:

```
C:\windows\system32\drive\etc\hosts
192.168.0.100 mypage1
192.168.0.100 mypage2
192.168.0.100 mypage3
```

batch programming in the windows, I can not do anything :-(

Thank you very much to help.
I am sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```bat
@For /D %%A In ("C:\dirs\*") Do @(Echo=192.168.0.100 %%~nxA)>>"%__AppDir__%drivers\etc\hosts"
```

Your output file would obviously need to be writeable, and the script probably Run as administrator.

Comment: Super! Thank You Very Much.;-)

Comment: It may be helpful if you were to mark this answer as correct.